# Java multiplication (in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, int))

Tags: java, integer, numbers, println

Table of a any number
getting this error - on System.out.println(number+" x "+i+" = ",+number*i);

(in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, int))

```
package JAVAS;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class number {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number ??");
int number = num.nextInt();
int i=1;
System.out.println("the table of the following number is ");
while (i <= 10)
{
    System.out.println(number+" x "+i+" = ",+number*i);
    i++;
}
        
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `System.out.println()` method that takes a String and an int as its two arguments.

Comment: In other words remove the comma from that line.

Comment: bruh...thanx.. i made that stupid mistake xD ..ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you have an extra comma in your println.  However, for clarity and to expose to you better methods of doing this, consider the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Enter the number ??");
        int number = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("the table of the following number is ");
        String format = "%d x %d = %d";
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            System.out.println(String.format(format, number, i, number * i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So based on both comments we should use `System.out.format()`. At least in my opinion.